# Skipping some characters when printing an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I am using the method below to print a map for a game using an array. How do I hide some characters (they don't have a particular pattern because they are randomly guessed by the computer) when I print out the array?:

```
public static void print2D(char[][] ocean_map) {
        int j = 0;
        System.out.print("  ");
        for(int i = 0; i < ocean_map.length; i++){
            System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (char[] row : ocean_map) {
                System.out.println(j + "|" + Arrays.toString(row) + "|" + j);
                j++;
        }
        System.out.print("  ");
        for(int i = 0; i < ocean_map.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: *"some characters"* That's difficult to say, since you haven't identified which "some" characters you'd want to hide. How would you decide which ones to hide? Once you know that, apply that decision with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Arrays.toString(row)` you can write a method to handle this for you. For example

```
String rowAsString(char[] row) {
    // this is the list of characters you want to show
    List<Character> whitelist = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c');
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : row) {
        final String toAdd;
        if (whitelist.contains(ch)) {
            toAdd = ch;
        } else {
            toAdd = ' ';
        }
        sb.append(toAdd);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```